# how to precheck form values which are in a different sql table before submit - symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a registration form with values client number, followed by name, address, email and password. 
The client number is not in the same sql table as other parts of the form, it's already predefined and once user submits a form I need to precheck client number in the sql table if the user entered one of the given.
Thereafter the user is registered and gets confirmation email. 
My solution was to separate it in two forms because it's quite tricky to get it working in one form, does anyone have a better idea?
here's one Code excerpt from User.php

```
class User extends BaseUser{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="type in your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * 
     */
    public $name;
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=50)
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="enter your client number.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * 
     */
    public $clientnumber;
    /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="integer", length=11)
     */
```

clientnumber doesnt belong to the form registration because it's in a different sql table but it needs to be checked before final insertion, in the abstraction layer I was only able to relate to one sql table.

Comment: my question is actually about how to check one of the values in the form which is in the sql table before the final submit

Comment: by `before the final submit` are you referring to ajax or to sequence validation?

Comment: it's submitted over ajax, it submits all values and i still have no idea how to precheck client number if it exists in another table because other elements belong to another table which are inserted there directly, that's quite tricky to implement it in configuration of symfony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **onPrePersist** method in User entity.

Update your User entity's doctrine orm file with fllowing.

```
<lifecycle-callbacks>
   <lifecycle-callback type="prePersist" method="prePersist" />
</lifecycle-callbacks>
```

And then update User entity file with following.

```
/**
 * @PrePersist
 */
public function onPrePersist()
{
    // verify the client number value from whatsoever entity here.
}
```